# Functors and natural transformations

Tags: functor, category-theory

If F is a functor linking category C to category D, and G is a functor linking category C to category E,(and assuming that both functors are bijections), does this imply that there is a unique natural transformation from functor F to functor G?

Comment: A natural transformation is between functors with the same domain and the same codomain, so that's where it already goes wrong?

Comment: Thanks.  Didn't realize that.